# GCP App Engine - Could not load the default credentials

Tags: authentication, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-authentication, service-accounts

I'm working on a project, that uses GCP and App Engine. In dev it will print out errors saying:

```
2020-09-20 15:07:24 dev[development]  Error: Could not load the default credentials. Browse 
to https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/getting-started for more information.      
at GoogleAuth.getApplicationDefaultAsync (/workspace/node_modules/google-auth-
library/build/src/auth/googleauth.js:161:19)      at runMicrotasks (<anonymous>)      at 
processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)      at runNextTicks 
(internal/process/task_queues.js:66:3)      at listOnTimeout (internal/timers.js:518:9)      
at processTimers (internal/timers.js:492:7)      at async GoogleAuth.getClient 
(/workspace/node_modules/google-auth-library/build/src/auth/googleauth.js:503:17)      at 
async GrpcClient._getCredentials (/workspace/node_modules/google-
gax/build/src/grpc.js:108:24)      at async GrpcClient.createStub 
(/workspace/node_modules/google-gax/build/src/grpc.js:229:23)
```

Keep in mind this is development mode, but is running on the GCP App Engine infrastructure, it is not being run on localhost. I'm viewing the logs with the command:

```
gcloud app logs tail -s dev
```

According to the GCP App Engine docs @ https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/production#cloud-console

```
If your application runs inside a Google Cloud environment that has a default service 
account, your application can retrieve the service account credentials to call Google Cloud 
APIs.
```

I checked my app engine service accounts. And I have a default service account and it is active. Please see the redacted image here:

[image: default app engine service account]

So I guess my question is: If I have an active default service account, and my application is supposed to automatically use the default service account key when it makes API calls, why am I seeing this authentication error? What am I doing wrong?

Edit: here's the code that is printing out errors:

```
async function updateCrawledOnDateForLink (crawlRequestKey: EntityKey, linkKey: EntityKey): Promise<void> {

  try {
        
    const datastore = new Datastore();
    
    const crawlRequest = await datastore.get(crawlRequestKey)
    
    const brand = crawlRequest[0].brand.replace(/\s/g, "")
    
    await data.Link.update(
      +linkKey.id,
      { crawledOn: new Date() },
      null,
      brand)
        
  } catch (error) {
        console.error('updateCrawledOnDateForLink ERROR:', `CrawlRequest: ${crawlRequestKey.id}`, `Link: ${linkKey.id}`, error.message)
  }
}
```

My prediction is that creating a new Datastore() each time is the problem, but let me know your thoughts.

Comment: Edit your question and include the code that generates the error.

Comment: Let me spend some time to narrow down the code block that's causing the issue. I'll reply with the code when I know.

Comment: Ok, I updated the post with the code in question. Hope you have some insight.

Comment: 2 more questions: Can you share your app.yaml file also? Can you share  your package.json file? Thanks

Comment: Removing the new Datastore() call to a global in two different functions (removing a local new Datastore() call) has caused the issue to go away. I've run the app to completion 5+ times and it hasn't shown up since.

Comment: The fact that removing `new Datastore()` from a couple of functions solves the issue indicates that the issue is not with Authentication with App Engine but it is with Datastore, which makes sense given the documentation piece you shared. So I would say that Datastore is getting lost with the credentials when you are creating multiple instances of it in your code. Do you actually need to do that in your logic?

Comment: No. I do not, so i turned it into a global Datastore() instance and just use the global from each of the functions that need it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fact that removing `new Datastore()` from a couple of functions solves the issue indicates that the issue is not with Authentication with App Engine but it is with Datastore, which confirms the documentation piece you shared.

I believe that the issue is that Datastore is getting lost with the credentials when you are creating multiple instances of it in your code for some unknown reason.

Since you mentioned in the comments that you don't really need multiple instances of Datastore in your code the solution to your problem is to use a single instance in a global variable and use that variable in multiple functions.